# How to take torque about a non-inertial point

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

> A uniform stick of mass M and length L is suspended horizontally with
> end B on the edge of a table, while end A is held by hand. Point A is suddenly released. Right after release, find the vertical force at B, as well as the downward
> acceleration of point A. You should find a result greater than g. Explain how this can be possible, given that gravity is the only downward external force in the problem.

This problem is 7.14 of Kleppner and Kolenkow. The solution given says to take torque about point B, claiming the net torque is simply MgL/2. I always thought that to take torque about an accelerating point (like point B), you needed to add a fictitious applied at the CM of the body. Where have I misunderstood.

Thanks for any help

Comment: *. . . . . about an accelerating point (like point B) . . . . .*  End/point $B$ does not move.